# How to create permalink pages for individual posts and notes on Tumblr

Tags: post, tumblr, permalinks

I'm currently creating my first custom theme for Tumblr and I can't find any explanation of how permalink pages for posts and that post's notes work or how they are written, how do I go about this? what is the code needed and where is it implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you want to appear on a permalink only page you want to have wrapped in `block:PermalinkPage` tags. If you only want it to show on the index page, wrap it in `block:IndexPage` tags.

To get your notes to show use `{block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:PostNotes}`. This will only appear on a permalink page (despite it not being wrapped in `block:PermalinkPage` tags. `{PostNotes}` creates an `ol` tag with a class of notes for you to style in any way you'd like.